# Como utilizar la GSMshield2639 con arduino mega

Tags: arduino

Estoy usando una placa de `sparkfun` llamada `MG2639` es para `GSM`. El problema es que no la puedo correr con `Arduino mega`, y necesito correrla en mega ya que mi código no lo soparta el `Arduino uno` o el `Arduino Leonardo` por falta de memoria.